# Read Array of Strings as Array in Pyspark from CSV

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a `csv` file with data like this

```
ID|Arr_of_Str
 1|["ABC DEF"]
 2|["PQR", "ABC DEF"]
```

I want to read this `.csv` file, however when I am using `sqlContext.read.load`, it is reading it as string

**Current:**

```
df.printSchema()

root
 |-- ID: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Arr_of_Str: string (nullable = true)
```

---

**Expected:**

```
df.printSchema()

root
 |-- ID: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Arr_of_Str: array (nullable = true)
      |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

How can I cast string to array of string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:**

Actually, you can simply use `from_json` to parse `Arr_of_Str` column as array of strings :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn(
    "Arr_of_Str",
    F.from_json(F.col("Arr_of_Str"), "array<string>")
)

df1.show(truncate=False)

#+---+--------------+
#|ID |Arr_of_Str    |
#+---+--------------+
#| 1 |[ABC DEF]     |
#| 2 |[PQR, ABC DEF]|
#+---+--------------+
```

---

**Old answer:**

You can't do that when reading data as there is no support for complexe data structures in CSV. You'll have to do the transformation after you loaded the DataFrame.

Just remove the array square brackets from the string and split it to get an array column.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import split, regexp_replace

df2 = df.withColumn("Arr_of_Str", split(regexp_replace(col("Arr_of_Str"), '[\\[\\]]', ""), ","))

df2.show()

+---+-------------------+
| ID|         Arr_of_Str|
+---+-------------------+
|  1|        ["ABC DEF"]|
|  2|["PQR",  "ABC DEF"]|
+---+-------------------+

df2.printSchema()

root
 |-- ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Arr_of_Str: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Comment: I tried this and works fine. As per the doc spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/… , return type is struct. Just curious how it works given input is not json string? can we use from_json to cast to any other dataypes other than struct?