# Why ArrayType doesn't applies to schema?

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I'm trying to read a CSV in Databricks (PySpark) with an array column; however, at the end the column supposed to be an array ends up as a string

**CSV File Head:**

```
index,week,location,visitors
0,2022-W14,XXXXXXXX,"[{'as_member': Decimal('1'), 'real_name': 'XXXXXXXX', 'as_guest': Decimal('0')}, {'as_member': Decimal('1'), 'real_name': 'XXXXXXXX', 'as_guest': Decimal('0')}, {'as_member': Decimal('1'), 'real_name': 'XXXXXXXX', 'as_guest': Decimal('0')}, {'as_member': Decimal('1'), 'real_name': 'XXXXXXXX', 'as_guest': Decimal('0')}, {'as_member': Decimal('0'), 'real_name': 'XXXXXXXX', 'as_guest': Decimal('1')}, {'as_member': Decimal('0'), 'real_name': 'XXXXXXXX', 'as_guest': Decimal('1')}]"
```

**CSV Reading Applied:**

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, StructType, StructField, ArrayType, IntegerType, MapType

schema_def = StructType([
  StructField("index_col", IntegerType(), True),  
  StructField("location", StringType(), True),
  StructField("visitors", ArrayType(StringType()), True)
])

raw_df = (spark.read
              .format("csv")
              .option("schema", schema_def)
              .option("header", True)
              .load("dbfs:/data.csv")
         )
```

Applying `raw_df.printSchema()`

**Expected Result:**

```
root
 |-- index: string (nullable = true)
 |-- week: string (nullable = true)
 |-- location: string (nullable = true)
 |-- visitors: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

**Actual Result:**

```
root
 |-- _c0: string (nullable = true)
 |-- week: string (nullable = true)
 |-- location: string (nullable = true)
 |-- visitors: string (nullable = true)
```

How can I get the Schema to actually cast the field `visitors` from String to Array?

Do I need to apply a transformation or is it possible to achieve during the read?

Comment: Your visitors data is surrounded by double quotes ("[...]"). Is it possible to replace all  "[ with [ and all ]" with ] in your text file and then try?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59303766/2956135