# Column has a data type of array<string>, which is not supported by CSV

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Input data is in csv format. One of the field called country has array of string data stored as string. I'm trying to read from PySpark and cast the country as array of string.

However running into error - Column country has a data type of array, which is not supported by CSV. Can we not cast string field which has array values as array while reading from csv?

sample record : 1,"[""us"",""uk"",""jp""]"

- id is 1
- country is "[""us"",""uk"",""jp""]"

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType,ArrayType
 
schema = StructType([
    StructField("id", IntegerType()),
    StructField("country", ArrayType(StringType()))
])

df = spark.read.option("header", "true").option("sep", ",").option("escape", '"').schema(schema_def).csv(<file_path>)
df.show()
```

Comment: You cannot directly cast a string representation of an array like that. you can read this string as a StringType and then convert it into an ArrayType using a transformation.

Comment: you are asking spark to read a string value as array. you should first read the data as is and then transform the string to array.

Comment: This can help you. Exact question.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/59303766/3238085

Comment: thank you. I tried from_json and it worked to cast as array of string.  As per the doc https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.from_json.html , return type is struct. Just curious how it works given input is not json string? can we use from_json to cast to any other dataypes other than struct?